# react-bootstrap Carousel breaks when changing content during transition

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, carousel, react-bootstrap

video of issue:

[image]

When the carousel is transitioning from one slide to another, if another entry from a dataset is choosen, before the slide finishes its transition, the new images are rendered, but controls/timer are broken, so the carousel is not slidable any more (manually or automatically).

activeFish is a useState object with some fish data that gets changed with setActiveFish(newActiveFishDataObject)  when a list item is clicked

Anyone have ideas for a solution?

```
  <Carousel>
    {activeFish['Image Gallery'].map((imageData, i) => (
        <Carousel.Item key={imageData.title + i}>
            <div className="image-container">
                <img
                    className="d-block w-100" 
                    src={imageData.src}
                    alt={imageData.alt}
                />
            </div>
            <Carousel.Caption>
                <p>{imageData.title}</p>
            </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
    ))}
</Carousel>
```

Replicate-
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-night-yckxro (thanks to @IgorGonak)

onload, immediately click the down arrow on the dropdown to expose options, mouse over option b, wait for transition to happen, click b rite in the middle of the transition. observe controls wont work for the 'b' dataset

Comment: What do you mean with "content mid transition"?

Comment: When the carousel is transitioning from one slide to another slide. The content would be the slides that make up the carousel

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please also include better details regarding the issue, including steps to reproduce.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks, updated description with more details

Comment: I ran Igor's sandbox yesterday, and yours today, and have tried following your reproduction steps. I don't understand the issue you are trying to highlight. The carousel slides change and the UI controls function as I'd expect them to. Can you clarify in more detail what the issue is? What specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the description with a gif of the issue, notice how 'option b' is selected while the transition is active, the slide had not reached the end position before 'option b' was clicked

Comment: That sort of seems expected IMO. If you change, i.e. replace, the underlying data it will trigger a rerender. The previous and next state doesn't coincide. You may need to use some extra state to merge the new "state" into the existing "state" and remove the existing "state" once the transition cycle has completed.

Comment: this would not be expected if this component is intended for dynamic data. Per the public methods/attrs that component exposes, you cant re-initialize the component(which is a basic functionality of many carousels), re rendering the entire component doesn't work either. the only way to make this work is waiting for transition complete event before changing which is kinda silly IMO

Answer (score -1):

I've created a dummy data with three entries and three images each entry. Then I built a select to select one and the carousel like yours - it is working on my side: When I choose another entry, the images in carousel are adjusted. The transition is working and is performed after each defined timeout:

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-night-yckxro

```
import React from "react";
import { Carousel, Form, Stack } from "react-bootstrap";
import data from "./fishData";

export default function App() {
  const [activeFish, setActiveFish] = React.useState(data[0]);
  const onSelect = (event) => {
    const choosenFishName = event.target.value;
    const choosenFish = data.find((fish) => fish.name === choosenFishName);
    setActiveFish(choosenFish);
  };
  return (
    <Stack className="m-3">
      <Form.Group id="fish-select" className="mb-3" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        <Form.Select value={activeFish.name} onChange={onSelect}>
          {data.map((entry) => (
            <option key={entry.name} value={entry.name}>
              {entry.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Form.Select>
      </Form.Group>
      <p>Choosen fish is: {activeFish.name}</p>
      <Carousel style={{ height: 200, width: 300 }}>
        {activeFish["Image Gallery"].map((img) => {
          return (
            <Carousel.Item key={img.title}>
              <img className="d-block w-100" src={img.src} alt={img.alt} />
              <Carousel.Caption>{img.title}</Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
          );
        })}
      </Carousel>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

**Edit:**

According to https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/6352 the problem here is that there is a state called "isSliding" in Carousel component. If it's true, the controls are deactivated. When we change children while sliding "isSliding" is true, but it's not set to false in the end, because the appropriate callback is never fired.

The solution is to reset the component by adding unique key to it:

```
<Carousel
    key={activeFish.name}
    interval={2000}
    style={{ height: 200, width: 300 }}
>
    {activeFish["Image Gallery"].map((img) => {
      return (
        <Carousel.Item key={img.title}>
          <img className="d-block w-100" src={img.src} alt={img.alt} />
          <Carousel.Caption>{img.title}</Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      );
    })}
</Carousel>
```

Comment: The issue is present in your example, how to replicate- onload, click the down arrow on the dropdown to expose options, mouse over option b, wait for transition to happen, click b rite in the middle of the transition. observe controls wont work for the 'b' dataset

Comment: Thank's for pointing it out. This is indead an interesting behaviour and looks like a bug. I tried to re-create the whole Carousel on select, but even then it remains broken. You have to dig deep to debug the problem. Must have something to do with the css transition. Maybe you could create a new issue on Github? https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues

Comment: Thank you for looking deeper into this, I am going to post this issue on their github.

Comment: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/6352

Comment: I edited my answer according to your github issue. Thanks for creating!